# Making a stacked bar chart in pandas seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to create a stacked bar graph where the x-axis is the provider, y-axis is the percentage and the stacks are the visit number. The visit number may change for example gastro may have percents up to 10 visits but pediatric may have 7 visits. I am not sure how to create the stacked graphs. This is the code I am using currently:

```
sns.barplot(x="provider", y="percentage",
                col="visit_number", data=df[df['visit_number'] == 1], kind="bar", palette=palette)
```

However, I get a separate graph based on visit number but I want it in one stacked graph. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.set_index(['provider','visit_number'])\
    ['percentage'].unstack()\
    .plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can specify the order in which the bars are displayed? Right now it is alphabetical.